# How to write a system of equations surrounded by a vertical bar?

Tags: equations, symbols, align

I have a small system of equations which should be displayed like the following:

[image]

I tried to display this with `\left.` and `\right\vert`. But this didn't work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \left.
            x^2-y+2=0 \\
            y^2-11y-6x+18=0
        \right\vert
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This try resulted in the following:

[image]

I think that`\left` and `\right\vert` is not made for such things but I didn't knew any better. The equations should be aligned too, but I already struggled with these vertical bars. I get no compilation errors. I already tried with the `systeme` package but didn't get it to work as well.

Comment: Do you come from some forbidden planet? 

Comment: I think you mean `\left\vert` rather than `\left.`, or, better, `\left\lvert` and `\right\rvert`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `systeme` package is for linear systems.

You want `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left|
  \begin{aligned}
    x^2-y+2&=0 \\
    y^2-11y-6x+18&=0
  \end{aligned}
  \right|
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some space between the bars and the equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left|\;
  \begin{aligned}
    x^2-y+2&=0 \\
    y^2-11y-6x+18&=0
  \end{aligned}
  \;\right|
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd use left alignment, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left|\;
  \begin{aligned}
    & x^2-y+2=0 \\
    & y^2-11y-6x+18=0
  \end{aligned}
  \;\right|
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a very understandable approach for me!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible solutions (there must be many more...). The first employs an `aligned` environment inside `\left\lvert ... \right\rvert`, the other uses a `vmatrix*` environment. The first solution renders its material in `\displaystyle` math mode, the second employ `\textstyle` math mode as well as tighter line spacing. I wouldn't say one approach is necessarily better than the other. It'll depend on the use case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'vmatrix*' env.

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
   \left\lvert \begin{aligned}
       x^2-y+2&=0 \\
       y^2-11y-6x+18&=0
   \end{aligned} \right\rvert \\[5mm]
   \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
       x^2-y+2=0 \\
       y^2-11y-6x+18=0   
   \end{vmatrix*}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```